# Flash Actionscript Update Field Method

Tags: flash, methods, printing, actionscript

Is it possible to get the values of a method which keeps updating a number in Actionscript?

```
function updateHNumber(): void 
{
    sliderHorizontalPumpe01qv.sliderValue = sliderHorizontalPumpe01qv.statqv.htmlText = sliderHorizontalPumpe01qv.handle.x;
    sliderHorizontalPumpe01qv.statqv.x = sliderHorizontalPumpe01qv.handle.x - sliderHorizontalPumpe01qv.handle.width;
}
```

so my method is updateNumber() which has an integer inside.
I want to print that integer in another function out.

```
function getPumpVolumenQv(e: MouseEvent): void 
{
    pumpeVolQv = Number(pumpeVolumenstromTextFieldqv.text);
    pumpeVolN = Number(pumpeVolumenstromTextFieldn.text);
    pumpeVolNg = Number(pumpeVolumenstromTextFieldng.text);
    pumpeVolumenstromTextFieldqv.text = updateNumber();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, using a `return` inside your function, but here you should change the return type for your function from [`void`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/specialTypes.html#void) to the type of the returned value.

So for your function, you can do like this :

```
function updateHNumber(): int 
{
    var local_var:int = 0;    // accessible just inside this function
    return local_var += 1;    // return the value of the local var for using externally 
}

trace(updateHNumber());       // gives : 1
```

You can also use a [`global variable`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f8c) which will be accessible inside and outside the function :

```
var global_var:int = 0;    // accessible here and inside the function
function updateHNumber(): void
{
    global_var ++;  
}
updateHNumber();
trace(global_var);         // gives : 1
```

For more details about **variables**, take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html), and about **functions** from [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/functions.html).

Hope that can help.